# Spacing in Word documents is different depending on the user

Tags: microsoft-office

When working with styles, some users can open documents and the spacing looks like it was intended to look; however, when other users open the document, the built-in spacing is suppressed.  We have not been able to identify why the spacing is accurate for some and not for others.

Comment: Is this different users opening the same document?  Or just starting a new document?

Comment: This is different users opening the same document.  We work with templates so all machines are supposed to have the same templates loaded, including the revised normal.dotm.  We didn't have this issue until we converted to Office 2007 so I'm wondering if there is something hidden in Office 2007 settings that we haven't been able to fine.

Answer (score 1):

I remember a long time ago, each user would mess with local settings and save them in normal.dot. Have you checked each machine to see if they have changed any settings?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that there is a font substitution occurring.  Microsoft Office will *NOT* inform the user of a font substitution, it will attempt to simulate the font, and that often will work on screen, but when printed, it'll look wrong.  Either the kerning will be wrong, or the font won't look just right.

Check the fonts on the system, and make sure that the document is using the right fonts.

MS Word will list the fonts that are being substituted, but I don't have my windows VM running right now...  Anyone willing to check to see what menu it's under?  (Edit --> Document Properties? I think).

Answer (score 0):

Is there still a normal.dot (normal.dotm) file that sets the defaults for a new document? Those can be different for different users.  But I think that's only for new documents.

Answer (score 0):

Word Styles are usually based on default styles stored locally.  If a style does not explicitly override the default style in some area, then any differences between one person's default style and another's will come through.

Resetting everyone's styles back to the default will solve the problem in the immediate.

Not basing styles on ever-changing default styles will solve the problem long-term.